# Merge statement

Tags: oracle, merge

I am looking into merge statements, but I can not figure out the syntax.

Let's say I have these tables

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
employee_id NUMBER(5),
first_name  VARCHAR2(20),
last_name   VARCHAR2(20),
dept_no     NUMBER(2),
salary      NUMBER(10));

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (1, 'Dan', 'Morgan', 10, 100000);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (2, 'Helen', 'Lofstrom', 20, 100000);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (3, 'Akiko', 'Toyota', 20, 50000);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (4, 'Jackie', 'Stough', 20, 40000);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (5, 'Richard', 'Foote', 20, 70000);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (6, 'Joe', 'Johnson', 20, 30000);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (7, 'Clark', 'Urling', 20, 90000);

CREATE TABLE bonuses (
employee_id NUMBER, bonus NUMBER DEFAULT 100);

INSERT INTO bonuses (employee_id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO bonuses (employee_id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO bonuses (employee_id) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO bonuses (employee_id) VALUES (6);
INSERT INTO bonuses (employee_id) VALUES (7);
COMMIT;
```

and just for the sake of an example I want to update all entries of bonuses with 200 * employee_id. Here is my statement. What's wrong with it?

```
merge into bonuses b
using
  (select employee_id id, 200 bonus from employees) test
on (test.id = b.employee_id)
when matched then update set
b.bonus = test.bonus * test.employee_id
```

Thanks!

P.S. See also my sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff425/14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
merge into bonuses b
using
  (select employee_id id, 200 bonus from employee) test
on (test.id = b.employee_id)
when matched then update set
b.bonus = test.bonus * test.id;
```

Two minor mistakes:

1) **employee** instead of employees

2) **test.id** instead of test.employee_id

Comment: Thanks! Glad to see it was just typos